# Get a Taxonomy values in an array

Tags: plugins, functions, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a Taxonomy type named: Products:product_cat

I need the term names inside this field in an array. Is there any way to get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve a taxonomies terms with [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/).

Via their docs:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));
```

And it returns:

> (array|int|WP_Error) List of WP_Term instances and their
>   children. Will return WP_Error, if any of $taxonomies do not exist.

Which you can view by doing somthing like

```
echo "<pre>".print_r(￼$terms,true)."</pre>";
```